# Not working on Android device

Tags: orbot, android, darknet

I've downloaded Orbot and Orfox several times over the last 2+ years but have never been able to access the dark web. I follow instructions and everything seems to be working right until I type in/click on the URL I'm trying to access; then it won't load. I've done this over WiFi and mobile data and still have the same problem every time. Somebody please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you used link with .onion?

Answer (score 2):

1. Check Orbot setting, could you able to see *NOTICE: Bootstrapped 100%: Done* if not you need to wait still it joins the Tor network.
2. OrFox - check Tor connection by visiting https://check.torproject.org on your browser. you should see a message, "*Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor.*
3. Then try accessing the website/onion sites. (make sure Orbot is running in the background and hasn't disconnected from tor network)

Answer (score 1):

You have to be on wifi with no restrictions like at your house. 
I can use orbot/orfox for regular sites but when I try to access onion sites it loads about 25% the way and stops. Normally, if a site is busy or under ddos attack tor will let you know. But, it doesn't go to that page. It continues to try to load the page never making it past 25%.
I found another app which works. Plain old Tor. Its one app. Go to play store and search Tor. No more having to use two apps. Just like tor on your pc. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

Tor develops a version of Tor Browser for Android. You can find it at the [download directory](https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/). This works similar to the Tor Browser for other operating systems which means you start the application. It then starts first Orbot and afterwards a specific instance of Firefox which is fully configured to send its connections over Tor. You can enter URLs and start surfing clearweb sites and also Onion sites.